# BCP bulk export stops before completeing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I'm trying to export 10943 files from my SQL database to files on my harddrive.
As I run the procedure it stops at 3529 files everytime. No error message, just stops as if it was done. Here is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KRAVFileExport] 
@OutputFilePath VARCHAR(500) = 'C:\test\'
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @totrow bigint
DECLARE @currow bigint
DECLARE @result bigint
DECLARE @nsql nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @sqlStatements table (ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),  SqlStatement 
varchar(max))   

INSERT
INTO @sqlStatements
SELECT 'BCP "SELECT [data] FROM [Krav].[dbo].[file] where idfile='+CAST(idfile as varchar(200))+'" queryout C:\test\'+CAST(sugarid AS VARCHAR(500)) +'.'+CAST(fileextension as varchar(500))+ 
  ' -T -f C:\test\fileformat.fmt'
  FROM combined_files
     SET @totrow = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @currow = 1
WHILE @totrow > 0 and @currow <= @totrow
BEGIN

  SELECT @nsql = SqlStatement
  FROM @sqlStatements
  WHERE ID = @currow

  EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @nsql
  SET @currow = @currow + 1
END
END
```

And here is an example how the sqlStatement table can look:

```
1129    BCP "SELECT [data] FROM [Krav].[dbo].[file] where idfile=21050001" queryout C:\test\6db38ce4-c943-11e6-a2d4-063b2f93642f.msg -T -f C:\test\fileformat.fmt
1130    BCP "SELECT [data] FROM [Krav].[dbo].[file] where idfile=21051001" queryout C:\test\6db38ce4-c943-11e6-a2d4-063b2f93642f.msg -T -f C:\test\fileformat.fmt
1131    BCP "SELECT [data] FROM [Krav].[dbo].[file] where idfile=21052001" queryout C:\test\6db38ce4-c943-11e6-a2d4-063b2f93642f.msg -T -f C:\test\fileformat.fmt
```

So, what could possibly be the problem?
Regards
Erik

Comment: Have you printed `@totrow` to know what its value is?

Comment: Yes, it is 10943

Comment: Have you inserted print statements to print the current iteration, i.e. `PRINT @currow;`. Does that end at 3529 as well?

Comment: Intrestingly enough the currrow continues printing out the correct number of rows and the bcp out says that it has written 7 rows. But still it doesn't create all files.

Comment: I'm seeing in your BCP commands in your question, that they are all written to the same file, i.e. `C:\test\6db38ce4-c943-11e6-a2d4-063b2f93642f.msg`. It's the same file for the three BCP lines you have in your question. Are you sure that all `combined_files.sugarid` values are distinct? I.e. if you do `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sugarid) FROM combined_files`, what value do you get?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use `combined_files.idfile` as the file name as that appears to be a unique column. Try that, see if you get the 10943 files this time.

Comment: Did you get to figure it out?

Comment: Yes after some figuring I did. It was a logical error. Apparently the structure was so that the company-key column was not unique. So it was overwriting the errors. Thank you for your help anyway!